# Style sheet preventing table cellpadding from working

Tags: html, css

I'm writing a web page based on someone else's stylesheet.  The stylesheet includes the following:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Now I want to create a table that has a non-zero cell padding.  But I am having trouble overriding this stylesheet:

```
<table cellpadding="10">
  <tr>
    <td padding="10">
      Foo
    </td>
    ...
  ...
  </tr>
</table>
```

and none of the above works; the cell padding stays a tight zero.

How do I override the stylesheet (short of using a different stylesheet)?

Comment: @Walkerneo - Just did, doesn't work.

Comment: Can you stick the style inline so you'd have - `<td style="padding: 10px;">`

Comment: @simnom - ah, when I do it on the `td` tag it works.

Comment: @Shaul, it didn't work on the `table` tag because you also need to undo the border-collapse. See my example for a true css replication of cellpadding that only requires you to put styles on the `table` element.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do in-line styling:

```
<td style="padding: 10px">
```

or assign a class to your `table` and create a rule for it:

```
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Foo
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and the CSS for this:

```
table td {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

try to be more specific in your selector, for example

```
table td {
    padding:10px;
}
```

The above will override

```
 th, td {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Learn more for CSS Specificity [here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).

Answer (score 3):

Just inline the necessary styles:

```
<table style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 10px;">
...
</table>
```

If you do this, you don't need the `padding="10"` on the `td` either. See http://jsbin.com/exovat/edit#html for a working example.

An alternative to inlining the styles is if you have access to your own custom stylesheet that loads after their stylesheet. Then you can set an id on the table like `<table id="foo">` and then just override their styles in your custom stylesheet like this:

```
table#foo {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 10px;
}
```

[Note: The `border-spacing` css property does  not work with IE7 or below; if you need those browsers to be supported, you are better off using some hackier method]

Comment: Nice idea but it comes out ugly and the text is still squashed right up to the borders...

Comment: @Shaul, well then what you want is just regular padding on table cells, not table cell spacing. They do slightly different things (cellspacing is part of the table as a whole, padding on table cells is part of the individual cells). So I'll leave my answer up here in case it turns out useful to someone else looking for a cellspacing solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use inline styles (ie styles declared on the element), inline stylesheets (ie styles declared in the same page but not directly on elements) or external stylesheets. Unfortunately CSS styles override attributes in most cases (I believe attributes such as you are using here are deprecated, meaning in essence use stylesheets instead).

Answer (score 1):

Create a new class for the table and apply it only to the tables you want to have this style.

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
    padding: 0;
}

table.newStyle { padding:10px; }


<table class="newStyle">
  <tr>
    <td padding="10">
      Foo
    </td>
    ...
  ...
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Same idea as @ZoltanToth but his solution is more elegant, so you only have to change the class on the table, not on every `<td>` tag